# Why is a value given to a return statement not overwritten by later return statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

assuming that an input was not equal to 1 or 2 (e.g. an input of 15), it would go through the loop, return false, but wouldn't that return value be overridden by the 'return true' underneath it that's outside of the for loop?

help to understand this would be much appreciated.

```
function checkIfPrime(numb) {
    if (numb === 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (numb === 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for (let x = 2; x < numb; x++) {
            if (numb % x === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

console.log(checkIfPrime(2));
console.log(checkIfPrime(15));
console.log(checkIfPrime(17));
console.log(checkIfPrime(19));
```

Comment: When you return, the function execution ends.

Comment: return true will only happen if it didn't hit an earlier return.

Comment: By far, the best way to understand this is to step through the code in the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser.

Comment: thank you very much everyone im really grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't that return value be overridden by the 'return true' underneath?

Well, no. When you `return false` the entire function execution stops and the `return` value is returned.

You give the example of `numb = 15`. Obviously 15 is not a prime number. The function will `return false` once `x =3` within the `for-loop`. At this point the function execution will terminate completely and return the value `false`. It will not progress to the `return true` statement at all.

For a prime number example, say `numb= 17`, the for loop will execute and the `if-statement` will never be true. This means the function execution will progress and the `return true` statement will be executed, thus making the function return `true`.

Check out this [W3 Schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp) for furter explanation of the `return` statement.

As T.J. Crowder suggested in the comments, using your IDE's debugger would be useful for you to follow the execution.

Comment: thank you very much im really grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

when return statement is executed, statements after return are not executed. Program leaves the function and go to the statement calling that function.

Comment: this is not very specific to the question.

Comment: but from the question it looks like that he does not know that the statements after return statement are not executed.

Comment: @PhilipBrack the question isn't about how to find a prime its about why the code example doesn't behave the way the person expects and this directly addresses the hole in their knowledge

Comment: thank you very much im really grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

return is different from a break; it doesn't just break out of the loop, but return the value for the whole function. Hope this helps.

Gav.

Comment: thank you very much im really grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

`return` is a terminator so the current code block exits upon meeting the statement

the behaviour you are describing would be created by this code

```
function incorrectCheckIfPrime(numb) {
    var returnValue;
    if (numb === 1) {
        returnValue = false;
    } else if (numb === 2) {
        returnValue = true;
    } else {
        for (let x = 2; x < numb; x++) {
            if (numb % x === 0) {
                returnValue = false;
            }
        }
        returnValue =true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}

console.log(checkIfPrime(2));
console.log(checkIfPrime(15));
console.log(checkIfPrime(17));
console.log(checkIfPrime(19));
```

Comment: @Ali i'm not sure what your point is, the question is why doesn't the second return override the first, and that's because return exits the code, if they want to override they need to store the return in memory before returning it so it can be overridden

Comment: thank you very much. i understand the difference between the two aswell. you put it in a clever way